# getting undefined reference to FaceRecognizer class in opencv3.2.0

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

Here is my code snipped where I am getting the error

> Error:- undefined reference to `cv::face::FaceRecognizer::predict(cv::_InputArray const&) const'|

Can anyone help me ,Thanks in advance

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face/facerec.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::face;


/*declaration of global variables */


int image_flag=1;//flag for depicting success/failure of reading a image
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
String face_cascade_name, eyes_cascade_name;
vector<int> labels;
Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```